# Finish loading image before executing other code

Tags: jquery, image, caching, onload

I am using a modal window to display pictures when they on a thumbnail.
However, the resized photo is not being loaded into the modal window.

The src of the image is not in my markup originally but I add it to the markup by appending it on the fly. I click on it the second time, the pic loads up in the modal.

When viewing the console, I am able to get the height and width the first time. The second time I get the height and width plus "the image is loaded" text.

I want to have a check to see if the photo is loaded and if it has completed, then execute the rest of the code. If it isn't loaded, keep on checking until it is loaded and then continue the execution for the rest of the code.

I have read other articles on stack overflow but none of them have worked for me. 
Can some please help.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    function galleryStart ($current) {


       var $tImage      = $current.find('img');
       var fullURL        = $tImage.attr('src');
       var $dFigure         = $('#dialog-media figure .media');
       var fullSrcURL = "images/mypicture"; 
       var fullSrcURL = fullURL.replace(".jpg", "_full.jpg"); 


       var image;

      function onload () {
        console.log(image.height, image.width);
        var objHeight = image.height;
      var objWidth = image.width;
      }

      image= new Image();
      image.src=fullSrcURL;

      if (image.complete) {
         console.log('image already loaded to browser');
         onload();
      } else {

         image.onload = onload;
         console.log('xxx');
      }

    $dFigure.append('<img id="dialog-media-object" src="' + fullSrcURL + '" alt="' +         $tImage.attr('alt') + '" />');

   //Execute more code here once the image has finished loading
   //More code to load the image into the modal window
}

$('a.dialog-media').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

            $("#dialog").dialog({
          height: "auto",  //720
          width: "auto",   //960
          draggable: false,
          modal: true,
          //position: {
          //          my: "center", 
          //          at: "center",
          //          of: window },
          open: function(event, ui){
              galleryStart(tLink);
          },
         close: function(event, ui){
              galleryEnd();
      $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();


});
```

}); // final closing tag

Comment: In this - `$('#dialog-media figure .media');` what is `figure`?  Should that be `$('#dialog-media-figure .media');` instead?

Comment: @Archer - `figure` is a new HTML5 tag.

Comment: Thanks @Steve.  I unfortunately have to cater for pre-HTML5 so haven't had chance to play with it yet.  I'm retro in a bad way :(

Comment: @Archer - I feel your pain... I actually had to look up `figure` just to confirm that I remembered correctly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the onload event for images as such:

```
image= new Image();
image.onload = onLoadHandler;
image.src=fullSrcURL;

function onLoadHandler() {
    alert("Image is loaded!");
}
```

Note: It is important that you assign the `onLoadHandler` to the `image.onload` BEFORE you assign the source.

So in your case, I would skip the whole `image.complete` statement and do something like this:

```
var $dFigure = $('#dialog-media figure .media');
var fullSrcURL = "images/mypicture"; 
var image;

function onload () {
  console.log(image.height, image.width);
  var objHeight = image.height;
  var objWidth = image.width;
  $dFigure.append('<img id="dialog-media-object" src="' + fullSrcURL + '" alt="' + $tImage.attr('alt') + '" />');
}

image= new Image();
image.onload = onload;
image.src=fullSrcURL;
```

Comment: Do I put the rest of the code in the function onLoadHandler to put the execution for the rest of the code once the image is loaded?

Comment: If the execution of your code is dependent on the availability of the image, then YES, you have to put that code inside the `onload` function (or at least trigger it from there).

Comment: I will try this out and let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create the DOM element with jQuery:

```
(function($){
    $(function () {
        // create image
        $('<img>')
            // add onLoad handler
            .load(whenImageIsLoadedFunction)
            // set the images 'src'
            .attr('src', 'your/image/source.png');
    });

    function whenImageIsLoadedFunction() {
        // do all your code here.
        $(this).appendTo('#imageContainer');
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I am not disagreeing with this answer, but for something this straight forward, a jQuery function is such a massive overhead that I would prefer the plain JS approach.

Comment: Well, you might have a point, if we were talking about thousands of images. But even if we would, the DOM API would say goodbye before JS even notices an overload.. Your solution by the way creates 2 image instances.